# Jest Accessibility Testing

Tags: testing, jestjs, accessibility

Hi i'm having an issue getting my jest test reading out my innerText with accessibility span tags. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

my content file is here

sr-only class is a screen reader only css class I added in

```
  "termsLabel": {
            "offerHeader": "{payment}/<span aria-hidden='true'>mo.</span><span class='sr-only'>month.</span> for {t_payments} years",
    }
```

My component brings in the content here. The way I have this setup is that it has to be dangerouslySetInnerHTML or else the spans show up instead of being hidden.

```
const card = ({ offer: { content } }) => {
    const { termsLabel } = content;
    const HeaderField = termsLabel?.offerHeader;

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="offer__row">
                {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger */}
                <strong className="offer__field-header" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: HeaderField }} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

My Jest Test

```
export const showInfo = async (modalContent) => {

    const offerFieldHeadline = await contentWindow.$eval(offerRow, element => element.innerText);
    expect(offerFieldHeadline).toContain(modalContent.offerHeadline);
    
};
```

OfferFieldHeadline is pointing to strong tag class of "offer__field-header"
offerHeadline has a config file set up like this

```
 modalContent: {
            offerHeadline: '$34.82/mo. for 6 years',
```

}

My output is

```
 Expected substring: "$33.17/mo. for 6 years"
    Received string:    "$33.17/mo.
```

This issue seems to be at .toContain and I can't figure out why half the message is not being outputed in the expect.

Comment: Doesn’t the tested solution here seem over-engineered to you, to simply save on 3 letters? `<abbr title="Months">Mo</abbr>` would be the more standard way to do that. Otherwise, screen reader users are used to abbreviations just as other users, it’s not necessary to spell everything out for them, I have been told.

Comment: I’m wondering why the closing quotes are missing in the copied output. Did you copy everything?

Comment: It was decided that to have the abbreviations written out for them. As for the quote, you're right the other half of the quote was not outputted which is strange